# Change CSS column balancing with three columns

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a layout that can be 1-, 2-, or 3-column depending on `@media`.

See https://jsfiddle.net/rcfpcdhq/

With three columns, when `(number of content divs) % 3 = 1`, the last column always is two divs shorter than the first two, though I'd prefer the first column be the only column with an extra div at the bottom (in the example, div count across columns would be 3-2-2 instead of 3-3-1).

Is this something that can be affected with CSS? I could use Bootstrap instead of `column-count` although I can't think of a way to maintain vertical ordering with columns using BS push/pulls.

Any ideas? Am I missing something obvious?

Only idea I have is to insert a spacer div after "div-5" which is hidden in 1- and 2-column layouts, in order to force "div-6" to the third column...

EDIT: To be clear, the order of the seven divs depending on number of columns, should be:

```
1-Column      2-Columns          3-Columns
--------      -------------      --------------------
[div1]        [div1] [div5]      [div1] [div4] [div6]
[div2]        [div2] [div6]      [div2] [div5] [div7]
...           [div3] [div7]      [div3]
[div7]        [div4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with columns because `column-count` fills the first column, then the second column, etc. 
And you want to fill by line and not by column.

---

You can do that easily without the columns, by making the DIV's float to the left.

Float to the left is used so that the DIV's will order themselves from left to right and then top to bottom.

Width is 32% (multiplied by three columns, it will give 96%) and the margin to the right is 2% (multiplied by the first two columns, it will give the final 100%). You can adjust as you please.

The `.content:nth-of-type(3n+0)` is there because otherwise the DIV's on the third column would have a margin to the right, making it 102% (or creating a useless space if you adjust it to 100%).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.content {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 32%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
.content:nth-of-type(3n+0) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  div-1
</div>

<div class="content">
  div-2
</div>

<div class="content">
  div-3
</div>

<div class="content">
  div-4
</div>

<div class="content">
  div-5
</div>

<div class="content">
  div-6
</div>

<div class="content">
  div-7
</div>
```

Your Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rcfpcdhq/1/

Comment: I thought you had it it, but now I see you're solution orders row by row, not down the columns. I need to order by column... see edit above...

Comment: @clemdia Well, like I said, there is no way to do that with `column-count` because it fills the first column (3 divs), then the second column (another 3 divs) and the remaining div will go to the third and last column. If you are open to use scripts, you can use them in two ways: 1) To order 1,4,6,2,5,7,3 and use the row by row solution (which will garantee balanced columns) or 2) Print 1,2,3 inside a first column, then 4,5 in a second column and then 6,7 in the third column.

Answer (score 0):

Add the extra **clearfix** for only the required viewport like  `.visible-xs-block`,  `.visible-sm-block`,  `.visible-md-block`, and  `.visible-lg-block`.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-6 col-lg-12">1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-6 col-lg-12">2</div>

  <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div> <!-- It works on medium size -->

  <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-6 col-lg-12">3</div>

  <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div> <!-- It works on small size -->

  <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-6 col-lg-12">4</div>

  <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div> <!-- It works on medium size -->

  <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-6 col-lg-12">5</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-6 col-lg-12">6</div>

  <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div> <!-- It works on small size -->

  <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div> <!-- It works on medium size -->

  <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-6 col-lg-12">7</div>
</div>
```

Now, you will have:

[1]

[2]

[3]

[4]

[5]

[6]

[7]

for large size,

[1] [2]

[3] [4]

[5] [6]

[7]

for medium size and

[1] [2] [3]

[4] [5] [6]

[7]

for small size.

Comment: See edit - I guess my initial question was not clear about the desired order of the divs within the columns. The content is to be ordered in columns, not by row...